# Java Concurrency - Queue Efficiency over List

Tags: java, collections

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz et. al. In chapter 5 it says

> "The Queue classes were added because eliminating the random-access requirements of List admits more efficient concurrent implementations".

Can someone please explain what this means?

Comment: It means that as you don't need random access for a queue it was better to introduce its own interface that doesn't require it.

Answer (score 4):

The random access requirements referred to are related to operations like:

- `T get(int)`
- `void add(int, T)`
- `int indexOf(T)`
- and so on.

The problem is that the position of an element in a list is potentially changed when you update the list.  For example, if I write this:

```
int pos = list.indexOf("fred");
list.add(pos, "jim");
```

in a multi-threaded application where other threads may update the list, then I need to synchronize the *sequence* of operations.

```
synchronized (list) {
    int pos = list.indexOf("fred");
    list.add(pos, "jim");
}
```

Noting that both `indexOf` and that `add` operation are typically O(N) operations, if the list is long, that is likely to lead to the list being locked for a long time<sup>1</sup>.  If other threads need to access the list in the meantime, they will be blocked.

By contrast the Queue APIs don't support random access operations, and a concurrent queue does not need to be locked for so long.  That means less blocking ... and better throughput.

---

<sup>1 - This is true even if ... hypothetically ... you had a "concurrent" list class where the individual operations did not block other threads for long.</sup>